# Getting weird numbers from array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I made function that splits given values(from array pointer) into bytes. For simplicity I use one byte values.
Why I'm getting weird numbers when I print values?

```
void writePage(uint16_t address, uint64_t *data, uint8_t const len, uint8_t const bPD)
{
    uint8_t pageBuffer[32];
    uint8_t bytes2Write = len * bPD;

    for (uint8_t dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < len; dataIndex++)
    {
        std::cout << int(dataIndex) << std::endl;
        std::cout << data[dataIndex] << std::endl;
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < bPD; i++)
        {
            pageBuffer[i + (dataIndex * bPD)] = ((data[dataIndex] >> 8 * i) & 0xFF);
            std::cout << int(pageBuffer[i + (dataIndex * bPD)]) << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t array[3] = { 255, 20, 30 };
    std::cout << int(array[0]) << int(array[1]) << int(array[2]) << std::endl;
    writePage(0, (uint64_t*)array, 3, 1);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output

> 2552030
>
> 0
>
> 119944479905023
>
> 255
>
> 1
>
> 70453687222272
>
> 0   2
>
> 0
>
> 0

Comment: `(uint64_t*)array` What are you doing with this? You have an array of `uint8_t` then pretend it's an array of `uint64_t`? What should that do?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It converts 8bit pointer to 64bit pointer. If i define pointer as `uint8_t*` then I can't pass 64bit array.

Comment: @SilvioCro you're *not* passing a 64bit *anything*. Pounding salt in the wound, it's only a `uint8_t[3]` you're doing it with. I dunno what math is like where you live, but even a *single* `uint64_t` requires *eight* octets; you're only delivering three. This code is loaded with *undefined behavior*. Do you know what `uint64_t` and `uint8_t` even *are* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig `uint64_t` is unsigned 8-byte, `uint8_t` is unsigned 1-byte. I'm trying to make "universal" function to "cut" value into bytes. Is it possible to make or I should make one function for 1-byte, 2-bytes etc..?

Comment: @SilvioCro _"It converts 8bit pointer to 64bit pointer."_ You're lying to your computer, then acting surprised when you get strange results :P You don't _have_ an array of 64-bit integers. Period.

Comment: Do you understand what `data[dataIndex]` does in your loop in `writePage` ? You're trying to enumerate *three* `uint64_t` values based on the `data` pointer improperly cast to `uint64_t*` from `main`, and `len`, the upper limit of your loop. It seems like you expect a `uint8_t[3]` will auto-magically transform into a `uint64_t[3]` just by that cast; that's not correct, and that's not what's happening. The cast effectively tells to the compiler "I know what I'm doing; treat this address like it points to `uint64_t` data", but it doesn't. Never did.

Comment: @WhozCraig So then it's impossible to make "Universal" function that will "cut" values into bytes no metter they are one byte or eight byte values?

Comment: @SilvioCro What are you really trying to accomplish? For what purpose is this "byte splitting" used for? This is sounding more and more like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm trying to make function that will cut/split given values(as array) into bytes. That function I'll use for writing into EEPROM(maybe I should go onto Arduino site but I think this is pure C++ problem). If I want to write value 10000 into EEPROM, first I have to cut that value into two bytes(first byte is 16, second is 39). Array of values can be one byte, two bytes etc... So I'm trying to make one function that will solve every array no matter what type is. Now guess it's not possible

Comment: @SilvioCro Why do you think it is impossible?  It looks like you are doing things the opposite way, i.e. your function should be taking a `char *` and work with that, not a pointer to a larger type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie isn't char just another name for uint8_t(byte)? Now I can't pass 8 byte value.

Comment: A `char` is a single byte, not 8 bytes.  And the classical way to "break down" or to "byte split" a type is to cast to a `char *` and work with the `char *`.  Again, you're doing things the opposite (wrong) way, where you are taking the type, and casting it for some odd reason to a `uint64_t *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to take any type,and to break up the bytes, the way it is almost always done is to cast a pointer to that type to a `char *` and work with the `char *`.

Here is an example using a stripped down version of your code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int x;
    double y;
    char z;
};

void writePage(uint16_t address, char *data, uint8_t const len)
{
    for (uint8_t dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < len; dataIndex++)
    {
        std::cout << (int)data[dataIndex] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t array[3] = { 255, 20, 30 };
    std::cout << int(array[0]) << " " << int(array[1]) << " " << int(array[2]) << std::endl;
    writePage(0, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&array[0]), sizeof(array));
    foo f;
    f.x = 10;
    f.y = 20;
    f.z = 'g';
    std::cout << "Here are the bytes of foo, which has a sizeof(foo) as " << sizeof(foo) << "\n" ;
    writePage(0, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&f), sizeof(f));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
255 20 30
-1
20
30
Here are the bytes of foo, which has a sizeof(foo) as 24
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
52
64
103
-54
-117
-54
-2
127
0
0
```

Comment: I still can't split `uint8_t array[3] = { 255, 20, 30 };` and `uint64_t array[3] = { 255000, 200000, 300000 };` with same function.
Also, first value is `255`, not `-1`

Comment: @SilvioCro -- What do you think `-1` is?  It is 255, but visually outputted as an `int` -- you want an `unsigned char`, then go right ahead and output that byte as an unsigned char, but you won't see anything, or will see a strange character.  The point is this -- you can access each byte in that loop -- it doesn't matter what is outputted.  Otherwise, what do you think that loop, which goes through each byte, is doing?  And also, do *not* rely on output functions to tell you what is the value in memory -- use a debugger if you need to be convinced that the type is being "splitted".

Comment: Also, it is surprising you're claiming to do low-level work using EEPROM, but determining if something works by looking at what `cout` is doing.  Shouldn't you be inspecting the actual memory using whatever debugging tools you have available?  Using `cout` is very poor if you want to see what is at that memory location.

Comment: [Here is the same code, with cout using unsigned char](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/152783e2adfd587a).  So nothing has changed, except the format of the output.   Also [what do you mean when you say you can't split the array](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6049f6aff44c3541)?  This code shows you it being splitted.

Comment: Does not know how it work, but it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works because as I've been saying -- if you want to take a type and see what each byte is, you cast the address of that type to a `char*`, and work with the `char *`.  For example, if you want to determine if a machine is big or little endian, you take a multibyte `int` type that is equal to 1, cast the address of the `int` to a `char*` (to isolate the first byte), and inspect that byte.  So in summary, `char *` is the universal type to break down a type into bytes.